# The \"Content-Type\" header VUE.JS conectada a una API REST de Symfony

Tags: vue.js, rest, symfony

una vez mas vengo pidiendo su ayuda para solucionar un problema en una aplicación realizada en VUE.JS, como consumidor de una API REST en Symfony, el problema es que es un proyecto que me dieron realizado por otra persona y no se como solucionar porque además estos framework no son mi fuerte, si se algo pero solo lo básico, dejo el código y el error que me esta mostrando, para explicarles un poco la situación lo que hacer es subir un archivo Excel mediante la pagina pero en el mismo método del repositorio de VUE.JS que sube el archivo a la API REST para su tratamiento y guardar la información a la tabla itinerario de la BD, con la respuesta del itinerario que es el archivo Excel ya analizado hace un llamado al método del repositorio que guarda la respuesta en la tabla rutas de la DB, y aquí es cuando se presenta el problema porque esta URL no esta funcionando. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

```
        async postRoutesFile({commit}, res) {
        try {

            const response = await RouteRepository.postRoutesFile(res);
            console.log('res1', response.data);

            if ( response.data.bStatus ) {
                const res2 = await RouteRepository.postRoute(response.routes);
                console.log('res2', res2);
                location.reload();
            }
             
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error,'store site')
        }
    },
```

Repositorio VUE JS

```
postRoute(payload) {
    try {
        const routes = Client.post(`${resource}`, payload, { baseURL: baseUrl });
        return routes
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error
        
    }
},

postRoutesFile(payload){
    try {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('itineraryFile', payload , payload.name)
        return Client.post(`${resource}/upload_itinerary`, fd, { baseURL: baseUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error            
    }
},
```

[image: Error]

[[image: Error y Detalle de la Respuesta2]

Como pueden ver el problema se da en esta linea
[image: Como pueden ver el problema se da en esta linea]

Answer (score 0):

El error es una Exception "UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException" de [Codigo 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

El mensaje del error dice que la API necesita especifiques el encabezado [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Tendrias que informarte con la documentacion de la API en cuestion para ver los requerimientos para que tu solicitud Post sea aceptada.

Me atrevo a listar algunas opciones que podrian ayudar:

1. Anade "Content-Type: application/json" o "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" en la peticion.
2. Convierte el objeto FormData en json antes de enviar la peticion.